# Save intermediate states of my Apache Spark pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a quite complex Apache PySpark pipeline which performs several transformations on a (very large) set of text files. The intended output of my pipeline are different stages of the pipeline. Which is the best way (i.e. more efficient but also more *sparkling*, in the sense of: more fitting the Spark programming model and style) to do this?

Right now, my code looks like the following:

```
# initialize the pipeline and perform the first set of transformations.
ctx = pyspark.SparkContext('local', 'MyPipeline')
rdd = ctx.textFile(...).map(...).map(...)

# first checkpoint: the `first_serialization` function serializes
# the data into properly formatted string. 
rdd..map(first_serialization).saveAsTextFile("ckpt1")

# here, I have to read again from the previously saved checkpoint
# using a `first_deserialization` function that deserializes what has
# been serialized from the `firs_serialization` function. Then performs
# other transformations.
rdd = ctx.textFile("ckpt1").map(...).map(...)
```

and so on. I would like to get rid of the serialization methods and of the multiple save/read -- by the way, does it impact the efficiency? I assume yes.

Any hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems obviously simple, because it is, but I would recommend writing the intermediate stages out while continuing to reuse the existing RDD (side bar: use datasets/dataframes instead of RDDs to get more performance) and continue processing, writing out intermediate results as you go.

There's no need to pay the penalty of reading from disk/network when you already have the data processed (ideally even cached!) for further usage.

Example using your own code:

```
# initialize the pipeline and perform the first set of transformations.
ctx = pyspark.SparkContext('local', 'MyPipeline')
rdd = ctx.textFile(...).map(...).map(...)

# first checkpoint: the `first_serialization` function serializes
# the data into properly formatted string. 
string_rdd = rdd..map(first_serialization)
string_rdd.saveAsTextFile("ckpt1")

# reuse the existing RDD after writing out the intermediate results
rdd = rdd.map(...).map(...) # rdd here is the same variable we used to create the string_rdd results above. alternatively, you may want to use the string_rdd variable here instead of the original rdd variable.
```

Comment: could you please improve your answer adding e.g. a link to some example and/or some reference code? Thanks.

Comment: @petrux, I provided an example above using your own code. I strongly recommend evaluating how you could use Spark 2.x (2.2 is most recent as of this writing) data structures such as Dataset and DataFrame (in python, only pyspark sql DataFrame, Dataset is not available like it is in Scala).

Comment: @Garrenn: thanks a lot. So I just need to save as text file. Good. Regarding the spark version, I am using 2.2. But I don't  know if using a DataFrame could be suitable for my task. Anyway, I'll take a look, thanks for the suggestion.